# Ruby Slim - How do you define an element's class with a rails helper or variable?

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, slim-lang

In rails slim (http://slim-lang.com/) the syntax for defining a new div with a class name "sample" is the following:

```
 .sample
      = "Content goes here"
```

this will create:

```
 <div class="sample">
      Content goes here
 </div>
```

I want to define a div's class according to a rail's helper, a variable, or other things.. such as, in rails:

```
 <div class="sample #{@variable.name}">
   Content goes here
 </div>
```

I have no idea how to do this in slim:

```
 .sample #what else goes here?
   Content goes here
```

Anyone know how?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

How about

```
div[class="sample #{@variable.name}"]
```

or even

```
div class=["sample", @variable.name]
```

or

```
.sample *{:class => [@variable1.name, @variable2.name]}
```

Comment: thanks. all three work. the first and second are the nicest format, but they all function. thanks again!

Comment: Another option, which I prefer: `div class="sample #{@variable.name}"`

Answer (score 9):

You can use parentheses, curly braces or just a space

```
.first-class(class="second-class-#{ruby_call}")

.first-class *{class: "second-class-#{ruby_call}"}

.first-class class="second-class-#{ruby_call}"
```

Answer (score 0):

For slim templates, I've been using the parenthesis notation.  You can add additional content on the same line with the equals sign ("="), but be sure to include a space:

```
h1 class=("sample #{@variable.name}") = @variable.to_s
```