# Ruby slim - class for a div from variable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

I am aware of this post here:

[Ruby Slim - How do you define an element's class with a rails helper or variable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851843/ruby-slim-how-do-you-define-an-elements-class-with-a-rails-helper-or-variable)

and I have tried all three solutions. For me unfortunately not one of them is working.

forum.rb

```
.panel
  .panel-heading
    .span  = @forum.name
  .panel-body
    .row 
      .col-md-7 #{t('global.topic')}
      .col-md-3.value.title 
      .col-md-1.value.topic 
      .col-md-1.value.date
```

forum_feed.js.coffee

```
window.ForumFeedUI = flight.component ->
  @defaultAttrs
    titleSelector: '.value.volume'
    topicSelector: '.value.topic'
    dateSelector: '.value.date'

  @refresh = (event, data) ->
    @update @select('volumSelector'), data.volume
    @update @select('topicSelector'), data.topic
    @update @select('dateSelector'), data.date
```

It all works as expected when I want to print the variables as text on the website. However I need the divs containing as well the variable for the title. Whatever I try I am unable to get the divs class with the variable of the title.

I believe I need to create a helper something along these lines and a content_tag:

```
content_tag(:div, content_tag(:p, "Hello world!"), class: "strong")


div = t(".#{forum_title title}")


def forum_title(title, &block)
  content_tag :div, class: "col-md-3-#{title}" do
    capture(&block)
  end
end
```

Comment: On which line exactly you're expecting to have a dynamic class?

Comment: @   .col-md-1.value.title

Comment: I am sorry but all the methods listed on the link you've posted works for me. I am sure that there's something wrong with the variables you've set. Please note that variables should be Ruby variables and not a JavaScript Variables!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could try:

```
.col-md-7 class="your-#{dynamic class}"
```

Comment: this gives me an empty class

Comment: this should give `<div class="col-md-7 your-something_from_variable"></div>`

Answer (score 1):

Use the alternate `[]` notation for css attributes.

These three lines are equivalent:

```
.col-md-6.title#foo Some content

div.col-md-6.title#foo Some content

div[class="col-md-6 title" id="foo"] Some content
```

For the last one, you can put Ruby `#{}` into the quotes, thus you can do this:

```
- myclass = "col-md-6"
div[class="#{myclass} title" id="foo"]
```

And IMO that's the easiest answer.