# How to do a multi-line class attribute with slim-rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, slim-lang

Element needs a lot of class attributes but I don't want them to be chucked in one line, as the line length will be too long and it would require heavy side scrolling.

Preferably, I don't want to use the delimiter syntax `[class= ""]` as this syntax would be entirely inconsistent with the whole file.

I tried doing this way:

```
span.select2.select2-container.select2-container--default \
  .select2-container--below.select2-container--focus
```

But the `\` and the remaining class attribute names just gets rendered as text.

Is there any possible way that I can chain class attributes in slim-lang a la ruby style, like this?

```
span.select2.select2-container.select2-container--default
    .additional-cssklass
    .whatever-class
```

Comment: You can find some useful syntax for slim [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12851843/ruby-slim-how-do-you-define-an-elements-class-with-a-rails-helper-or-variable?answertab=active#tab-top). However, I think if you want to stick with current syntax then there is no way to do.

Answer (score 5):

You need to use splat attribute that allows you to turn a hash into attribute/value pairs and then append a backslash to do multiline :

```
.first-class *{class: ["second-class", \
                       "third-class"]}
```

Comment: Yes, this works but I am looking for a way(if that is supported) to chain class attribute without doing a splat or using a delimiter.

Comment: I don' believe that is possible.